# sendOutputTo in Laravel Console

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I scheduled a cronjob through Laravel console. It is working and giving the result in every minute. But I tried to write the output to a file using the `sendOutputTo` and `appendOutputTo` method. But this is not writing to the file. My file has write permission.

Below is my code:

**Kernel.php**

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {

  $filePath = base_path() . "\cron\CleanSession.txt";

  $schedule->command('cleansession')
           ->everyMinute()
           ->sendOutputTo($filePath);
}
```

**Session.php**

```
public function handle() {

        $this->info('Display this on the screen');
        $onlineCodeObj = new OnlineCode();
        if ($onlineCodeObj->cleanSession()) {
            echo "SESSION CLEANED : echo" . "\n";
            return "SESSION CLEANED: return" . "\n";
        }
         echo "SESSION CLEANED : echo2" . "\n";
         return "SESSION CLEANED: return2" . "\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue. Changed the path

`$filePath = base_path() . "\cron\CleanSession.txt";` to `$filePath = base_path() . "/cron/CleanSession.txt";`